# Using InnerHTML on 144 different cells

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am creating a tile based game using tables. In each td cell,

```
 <td>
 <div id="image" style="display:none; display: fixed; right: 5; top:2;"><img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/339217/339217,1272881114,1/stock-vector-hand-drawing-of-typical-house-along-the-canal-near-bangkok-in-thailand-52242874.jpgAttap"/></div>
<input id ="attap" type="submit" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv(); if(submitted)this.disabled = true" />
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;"> <input type="submit" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv3(); if(submitted)this.disabled = true" /></div>
<div id="welcomeDiv3"  style="display:none;"> <input type="submit" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv4(); if(submitted)this.disabled = true"" /></div>
<div id= "welcomeDiv4"  style="display:none;"><input type="submit" name="answer"   value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv5(); if(submitted)this.disabled = true"" />    </div>
</td>
```

Javascipt:

```
    function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('image').style.display = "block";
submitted = true;
populationred +=20;
 document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = populationred;
} 
function showDiv3() {
document.getElementById('welcomeDiv3').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "'<img src='http://www.sgshophouses.com/images/Shophouses1.jpg'>'"
submitted = true;
 populationred +=50;
 document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = populationred;
 }
 function showDiv4() {
 document.getElementById('welcomeDiv4').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "'<img src='http://singaporepropertylaunch.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/HDB-resale-prices-fall-1.0.gif'>'"
  submitted = true;
    populationred +=100;
  document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = populationred;
  }

 function showDiv5() {
 document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "'<img src='www.realestatechannel.com/assets_c/2010/06/Austonian-Condo-Tower-thumb- 120x238.jpg'>'"
submitted = true;
populationred +=200;
 document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = populationred;
}
```

I need to repeat this for 144 cells. However, the problem is that when 1 button is clicked, the image will show up only at the first cell, hence the tedious way of solving this issue is to rename all the divs differently for every cell. Is there any more efficient ways?

You can refer here: www2.hci.edu.sg/t0104448b/cells.html for a "fiddle".

Comment: You can only use ids once per page, so having lots of elements all with id="welcomeDiv" etc will not work.

Comment: It's not very tedious to add an id/class programatically... You can change them by iterating. You can store your images in an array.

Comment: @Andy he doesn't have lots of elements all with id="welcomeDiv"

Comment: According to the question the OP has multiple cells each containing the same set of elements with the same ID.

Comment: @Andy no he doesn't, they are incremented.

Comment: The fiddle confirms it. One table with one row, and each cell the same elements with the same ids.

Comment: Get rid of all the ids. Create a two-dimentional array inside your code that represents your gamestate. Create one function that will make a html node for 1 'gameboard cell' instead of a seperate function for each cell. Loop that function over your array so that your gamestate gets translated into html nodes. Append all the nodes to a documentFragment. Replace your current board with the document fragment.

Comment: Or make an iterative function for all the cells and change the id/class as you go.

Comment: can anyone show me an example?

Comment: nope, it's my personal project, i'm just using my school ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shilly's comment had the right idea. I'm not entirely sure what your goal is but this is what I did, that looks reasonably what you're after. It should get you started.

There's only one click handler, on the `<table>` itself. It's effectively delegating the click. This saves memory because you're not creating a copy/closure for every cell. It costs some performance due to the delegating nature but for click handlers, it's generally okay. For mouseover handlers, that's another subject.

Using a `<template>` tag effectively gives you a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to work with and markup as HTML, instead of doing it in JavaScript (which can be tedious).

We clone that document fragment 144 times, injecting the proper description (`'ShopHouse', 'HDB Flat', 'Condo'`, etc.) into each stamp of the template. Each clone is appended to a document fragment. Once our document fragment is done being modified, we inject it into the DOM via `board.appendChild(frag);`.

```js
var board = document.getElementById('board');
var cellTmpl = document.getElementById('template-cell');
var cellTmplContent = cellTmpl.content;
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); // for performance

var submitted = false; // not sure what you intend to use this for

var descriptions = [ 'ShopHouse', 'HDB Flat', 'Condo' ]; // ... etc.

var cells = [];
for (var r = 0; r < 12; r++) {
  var row = [];
  cells.push(row);
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  frag.appendChild(tr);
  for (var c = 0; c < 12; c++) {
    var clone = document.importNode(cellTmplContent, true);
    var index = r * 12 + c;
    var description = index < descriptions.length ? descriptions[index] : 'Unknown place';
    clone.querySelector('p.description').innerText = description;
    tr.appendChild(clone);
    row.push(clone);
  }
}

board.appendChild(frag);
board.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var button = e.target;
  var td = button.parentElement;
  var img = td.querySelector('img');
  var p = td.querySelector('p.description');
  
  button.disabled = true;
  img.style.display = 'block';
  p.style.display = 'block';
  
  submitted = true;
});

// could do something with `cells` variable if you like. It's a two dimensional array of <td> elements
```

```css
td {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td > img {
  display: none;
  zoom: 0.2;
}
p.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
</table>

<template id="template-cell">
  <td>
    <img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/339217/339217,1272881114,1/stock-vector-hand-drawing-of-typical-house-along-the-canal-near-bangkok-in-thailand-52242874.jpgAttap"/>
    <button>Show</button>
    <p class="description"></p>
  </td>
</template>
```